# Jquery ajax abort() gives error on console

Tags: jquery, ajax

My jQuery code (below) method gives following error:

> TypeError: jQuery111007245809631238611_1456231588251 is not a function

```js
    $(function() {
      // Ajax request sent.
      var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wbB3lVyUvAM?v=2&alt=jsonc',
        data: {
          format: 'json'
        },
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          $('#info').html(data.error.message);
        },
        type: 'GET',
        error: function() {
          if (xhr.statusText == 'abort') {
            $('#info').html('Aborted!');
            return;
          }
          alert('error');
        }
      });
      // Abort ajax request on click


      $('#btn').on('click', function() {

        xhr.abort();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<button id="btn">click to abort </button>

  <div id="info"></div>
</body>
```

(also available at http://jsfiddle.net/e3ok3s6e/3/)

Is there any possible way to fix this error?

Comment: I am not getting the error that you have mentioned above.

Comment: Open the console, and click the 'click to abort' button in  jsfiddle,  while the loading.. appears. Not after the data has loaded.

Comment: To get that error one has to be very quick in terms of clicking the abort button.

Comment: Yes, but this shouldn't happen. I am in a situation where the service is slow, and the user has the option to cancel the request. The abort method is working fine but once we get response from the aborted request, the error appears.

Comment: Thanks... will look into it...

Comment: Check if xhr is active before you can abort it. set xhr as a global variable, then in your click function check if( xhr) { xhr.abort(); }

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

dataType:'json' in your request..

```js
    $(function() {
      // Ajax request sent.
      var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/wbB3lVyUvAM?v=2&alt=jsonc',
        data: {
         dataType:'json'
        },
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          $('#info').html(data.error.message);
        },
        type: 'GET',
        error: function() {
          if (xhr.statusText == 'abort') {
            $('#info').html('Aborted!');
            return;
          }
          alert('error');
        }
      });
      // Abort ajax request on click


      $('#btn').on('click', function() {

        xhr.abort();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="info"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain why or how this solves the problem? JSONP requests simply cannot be aborted (you can only remove the callback function), so I'm not sure how this answer solves the problem.

Comment: Using `dataType:'json'`, is not supported in this case, you can check the response in console.

Comment: As we cannot abort a jsonp request, this plugin will solve the issue: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp